# Generate QGIS maps automatic after updating an Access 2010 or Filemaker Pro 12 database

Tags: qgis, ms-access

I want to develop a database which consist an interaction with QGIS. After updating the data in the database I want to push on a button and start a process in QGIS. After finishing the process in QGIS I want to import the results in the database. Therefor I need or want to build an executable which starts a process in Python. The part in QGIS is already covered, but is it possible to start the processes in QGIS with an external executable? I have found information about starting an external executable from Python, but I want to do it the other way round. Has anyone experience with starting Python processes from an executable? And which executable can be recommended?

Thanks in advance.